# How is the elevator inspection area on top of an elevator accessed?

Tags: walls, safety

Does anyone know or have any experience with how one typically accesses the inspection area on top of most elevators?

It's a fairly large set of elevators in a 20 story building if that makes a difference.

I know that it's not through a hatch in the ceiling as these are only openable through the top of the elevator to prevent accidents in case someone is stuck inside and tries to escape themselves.

Please don't respond if your advice is to tell me to contact the elevator company or a service professional.

Comment: Imagine most of the machinery would be housed in a building on the roof.  There are also probably some access doors on floors to enter the elevator space itself.  These might be hidden from normal people living/working there, either locked or in maintenance halls/rooms. I know bad wording about normal.

Comment: There are various enlightening videos on YouTube under `elevator hacking` that may provide insights into typical configurations. Another useful search is `elevator maintenance`.

Comment: @HABO  Think I take stairs next time.

Comment: What's your situation that is driving you to access the cartop? That's a fairly hazardous place to be...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I want to know how and from where someone is getting up there. Was hoping someone had some experience.

Comment: @HABO thanks for the video. I see at 17:00 it looks like what I expected they flip the switch in the elevator control panel to inspection mode then get in from the floor above by opening the doors using a firefighter key. I was trying to rule this out and was trying to figure out if there was a more purpose-built access point like an button/entrance in a mechanical room that didn't require opening the exterior elevator doors to the open shaft.

Comment: A building I am familiar with has stairs that go up to the elevator mechanical room as well as roof access

Comment: @DavidSmith -- does your elevator controller have logging functionality?

Comment: This vid from Defcon22 may have the info you want. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHf1vD5_b5I

Comment: Well as my brother-in-law’s was the chief elevator inspector in Tennessee and I have way in the past accompanied him on inspections none of the clowns have a clue!!! But I vote to close as this is not a diy question!!! The way they inspect the top depends on the brand like Dover / Otis the inspector sends the car below the floor they are on then waits and guesstimates when to open the doors on the floor above the car, once the doors are open the inspector climbs on top of the car and has full control of the car. If you are talking about the machine room electrical code has specifications VTC

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because elevators are never DIY and require licensed electricians in the US and many other countries.

Comment: Thanks @EdBeal for confirming that. My elevator has an inspection switch inside the locked control panel. Btw I checked my local elevator code for the city of los angeles which says that all work needs to be done by a journey-level certified person but says nothing about a simple inspection or access to any area as requiring any special licesning or qualifitications. Also, a good number of private homes here have elevators in them too.

Comment: @izzy where are the stairs you mention located? Behind the elevator shaft by any chance? your mechanical room on the 3rd floor above ground (6th floor from the bottom floor) by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

David, I am not sure if you doing the inspection is legal in California without training.

To answer how it is done My brother-in-law would go to the second floor and call the car then send it to the first floor. (Or send it to the basement from the first).
If only 1 elevator he would hang a sign that said maintenance was on the roof of the car and it may stop unexpectedly but would go to the top then down.

There is a special key that goes in the elevator door to release them.
this also stops the elevator (the small hole high up on one of the doors).

The controls on top of the car override the car controls I do not remember these requiring a key but these trips were in the early 80’s so I may have forgotten.

Once on top of the car the door lock mechanism and wiring chases can be inspected inside the hoist way.

Without safety training I believe this would violate OSHA laws as you can get hurt up there. You might ask your service company if you could ride along on one of there inspections and scope out the door release key it would not be hard to duplicate if they have not changed the design.